# How to Loop Through CheckBoxList and insert if Box is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I would like to loop this code and save selected CheckBoxList items. How should I do it?

```
String insCmd = "Insert into Sale (Name, price) values (@Name, @price)";
SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, myConnection);
insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text));

try
{
  myConnection.Open();
  insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
  myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception er)
{
  Response.Write("<script>alert('Error While Input')</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
connection.Open()
var insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, connection);   

foreach(var item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
  if(!item.Selected) continue;
  insertUser.Parameters.Clear();
  // your code where you can use Item.Text to add parameters
  // i have no idea about your textboxes though 
  insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
connection.Close();
```

But this is not the optimal way. Optimal way will involve table valued parameters and stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to iterate through the selected items.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection())
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        const string query = "INSERT INTO Sale (Name, Price) VALUES (@Name, @Price)";
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            foreach (var item in CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected))
            {
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", item.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Error While Input')</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         var items = new System.Collections.ArrayList(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems);
>         foreach (var item in items)
>         {
>             //your function for saving
>         }
> ```

Or, redo your insert function, pass collection of selected things, and concatenate your insert with all values u checked and execute query with 1 go to make it faster/efficient

Comment: He uses web control `CheckBoxList` which is different and doesn't have `CheckedItems` property.