# Copying one datatable selected column to another data table

Tags: asp.net

I have a datatable, then I have all the column names of the datatable as checkbox, I want to display only those column records, for which user selected from the checkbox:
Below is the code, but I am not getting the desired result

```
var values = "";
            string clmnm = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < interestedIN.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (interestedIN.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    values += interestedIN.Items[i].Value + ",";
                }
            }

            values = values.TrimEnd(',');
            string[] words = values.Split(',');



            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)Session["dataset"];
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                dt1.Columns.Add(word, typeof(string));
                if (clmnm == string.Empty)
                {
                    clmnm = word.Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    clmnm += "," +word.Trim();
                }
              }
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string[] split = clmnm.Split(',');
                int j =0;
                string str = "";
                string str2 = "";
                while( j < split.Length)
                {
                    str = split[j].ToString();
                    if (str2 == string.Empty)
                    {
                        str2 = "dr[\""+str.ToString()+"\"]";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str2 += "," + "dr[\""+str.ToString()+"\"]";
                    }

                    j+=1;
                 }
                dt1.Rows.Add(str2);         
            }
```

then I am trying to export the result as an excel sheet: but getting the below excel sheet:
[image]

Comment: How are you displaying result? `GridView`?

Comment: No, actually I am exporting the result as an excel sheet.. I mean the dt1 table..

Comment: I have added some more update..

Comment: Using `CheckBoxList` to display columns?

Comment: yes I am using CheckBoxList whoes id is interestedIN

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know if any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of changes to be done to your code. Lets begin with selected columns from `CheckBoxList`. Try using `List` or `Array`s to store which columns that user wants. Like

`List<string> columns = new List<string>();`

Then store the selected columns into the `columns` list. Then you need to add columns to your new `DataTable` `dt1`. As,

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < interestedIN.Items.Count; i++)
{
     if (interestedIN.Items[i].Selected) //If user selected this columns checkbox.
     {
         columns.Add(interestedIN.Items[i].Text.Trim()); //Storing values to List.
         dt1.Columns.Add(interestedIN.Items[i].Text.Trim()); //Adding columns to the DataTable.
     }
}
```

Then you can loop through your original `DataTable` `dt` and store the values as below.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow(); // Create new row which should have identical structure for inserting.
   foreach(string col in columns)
   {
      dr1(col) = dr(col);
   }
   dt1.Rows.Add(dr1); //Add the row with the contents to the table.
}
```

Comment: Giving exception like :   `"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'".`

Comment: it is giving an error like "object does not contain defination for selected" in `if (chk.Selected)` in the first foreach loop

Comment: @srikanta Is it really `CheckBoxList`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515145/how-to-loop-through-checkboxlist-and-insert-if-box-is-checked

Comment: The whole code above am writing in code behind, and in application page I wrote the following  ` <asp:checkboxlist id="interestedIN" runat="server" repeatlayout="table"
    cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" Font-Size="12px">
  <asp:ListItem id= "status" runat="server"  text=" Status" Selected="true" />
  <asp:ListItem id="firstName" runat="server"  text=" FirstName" Selected="true" />
  <asp:ListItem id="lastName" runat="server"  text=" LastName" Selected="true" />
</asp:checkboxlist>`

Comment: @srikanta Then `Selected` should exists as I provided a link in my previous comment.

Comment: Done.. It saves my life..Thnx